# Determining max virtual address space

Tags: byte, memory-address

> Given a system using a single-level page table, where each page table
>   entry in the page table is 4 bytes in size. A virtual address on this
>   system is of size 32 bits, with a 22-bit virtual page number and a
>   10-bit offset field. The page table limit register on this system is
>   currently set to 40. What is the maximum number of bytes of virtual
>   address space accessible at any time?

Okay so a single-level page table means one entry per virtual page. A virtual address of size 32 bits and 10-bit offset field means virtual page number field = 32 - 10 = 22 bits. Assuming a base register of `x`, the legally accessible addresses are between `x` and 40 (the given page table limit register). But how do I compute `x`? And is that my final answer for the maximum number of bytes of virtual address space accessible?